# How to build an advanced search form by post type?

Tags: search

I'm trying to build an advanced search form by post type.

For example...

I have custom Post Type : Locatie
Taxonomy : locatii

I have categories in PostType :

Categories:

-Orase - Arad
       - Alba....

-Tip - Puncte de livrare
     - Gaze Medicale

I want to get all post in that categories..

For example i select Arad and Gaze Medicate... and shoud apear me all the Medical Point for city arad.

```
<form method="get" name="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">

<fieldset>
<legend>Centre de distributie:</legend>
<form>
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="135"><b>Selecteaza oras :</b></td>
    <td width="359"><select name="locatie">
<option value="alba">Alba</option>
<option value="arad">Arad</option>
<option value="arges">Arges</option>
<option value="bacau">Bacau</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<div class="ti"><b>Limiteaza cautarile</b></div>
<div class="linie"></div>

<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="20"><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td width="160">Punct de livrare</td>
    <td width="25"><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td width="109">Parteneri logistica</td>
    <td width="35"><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td width="137">Agenti</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Gaze Medicale</td>
    <td><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Propan</td>
    <td><input name="produs" value="1" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Refrigerenti</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="sub">
<input class="art-button" type="submit" name="search" value="<?php _e('Search'); ?>" />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your search form, add an input with `name="post_type"` and `value="customposttypehere"`.

You can either have this as a hidden input or a text entry or a combobox or radio buttons etc, so long as it's inside the search form.

The same is true for any other query vars like post_type etc that you would normally put in WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into [pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). A great starting tutorial on this is by Pippin Williamson, [Using pre_get_posts to Modify Queries for Meta Data and More](http://pippinsplugins.com/using-pre_get_posts-modify-queries-meta-data-more/) (helped me out immensely).